# How to get the node based on the child node value using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
var xmlTst='<Tests>
                <Test>
                    <Id>123</Id>
                    <Name>AAA</Name>
                </Test>
                <Test>
                    <Id>456</Id>
                    <Name>BBB</Name>
                </Test>
            </Tests>';

$("Test>Id[text=" + 123+ "]", xmlTst).parent();
```

Above selector selects the first node of the above xml in IE. This doesn't work in Chrome.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Does using [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) work?

Comment: Contains doesn't work for me because if the id is 123456 it returns multiple result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your opening and closing tags does not match, but anyway :

```
var xml = $.parseXML(xmlTst);

$('Test > Id', xml).filter(function() {
    return $.trim( $(this).text() ) == '123';
}).parent();
```

Comment: What if I have another node with Id 123456 ? Does it return only one record or multiple ?

Comment: That would return multiple. Edited the answer.